# Where are the Iron Golem spawn eggs?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm running a modded version of Minecraft 1.12.2 and I can't find any spawn eggs for Iron Golems in my creative inventory.

Here is a list of my mods:

- Backpacks
- Coherent Villages
- More Furnace
- Tiny mob farm
- Cxlibray
- Tinkers Construct Libray
- Mantle
- Jurassic Craft
- Power Drop
- Iron Chest
- Tree Chopper
- Xray
- JEI
- Journey map
- Flans mod
- Build Craft

I can spawn all the other mobs fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iron golems can not be spawned with spawn eggs like with other mobs. Like a snowman, you need to build a shape and then put a carved pumpkin on top. The shpe you need for iron golems is one iron block on the bottom, then three on top with the one on the bottom being in the center of the top three, then put the pumpkin in the middle of the three, and directly above the original block.

[image: Iron Golem Formation]

If you want more info, you can look at the [creation section of the wiki.](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Iron_Golem)

Comment: Thank you this is perfect also do you know where I can post modded questions as i posted another one early and it was flagged by numerous people

Comment: @NoahShort Questions about mods are fine, but questions about problems with mods, like your previous question, are not. If you have any problems with mods, try that mods forums.

Comment: You can also use command blocks and/or the command field to enter the /summon command to summon a golem, if you have cheats enabled.

Answer (score 2):

[K00lman's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/364490/) is both **true and false**. Yes, you CAN'T actually find a spawn egg for an iron golem, but you can make one using commands. Since you are running 1.12, let's go with that command style.
The command is:

```
/give @p minecraft:spawn_egg 1 0 {EntityTag:{id:"minecraft:villager_golem"}}
```

There is only one problem here. You cannot just right-click with the egg and expect it to summon something. You can only put it in a mob spawner for it to work. If you don't know how to get a mob spawner (I doubt it), here is the command:

```
/give @p minecraft:mob_spawner
```